# Establecer ancho de un framelayout con kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo una imagen que es el fondo de un *FrameLayout*, que a su vez ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo">
```

Como la imagen es cuadrada necesito que el frame tenga un alto igual al ancho de la pantalla, el cual varia según el equipo, así que use un condigo para tomar el ancho de la pantalla en pixeles.

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
var ancho = displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

Hice algunas pruebas para ver si arrojaba los anchos correctos según diferentes equipos y hasta ahí todo bien, lo que no logro es traspasar este ancho a largo del *framelayout*, estuve probado con este código:

```
val frameLayout = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.frame)
frameLayout.layoutParams.height = ancho
```

Pero nada... no me funciona... agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente define en los parámetros del layout la medida de ancho que requieres

```
var params = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ancho)
```

y este valor lo configuras en tu FrameLayout

```
frameLayout.layoutParams = params
```